# Eliminating opacity mask flicker when setting Button.Visibility = Visible in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to figure out a way to eliminate a flickering effect I'm getting when I set `Visibility = Visible` on some buttons in my app.

My app has a `ListBox` containing about 100 items. I'm styling the items with a `DataTemplate`, and each `ListItem` contains two `Button` elements. When the app launches, one of the button elements is set to `Visibile`, and the other is `Collapsed`.

I am also using an `OpacityMask` on the buttons to enable them to change colors with the user's color scheme (light or dark).

When I toggle the visibility on the buttons for the very first time--i.e. hide one and show the other, the toggle hesitates for a second, then the opacity mask flashes briefly before it loads the icon image. The effect is that you see a split second pause, then a white square around the icon, then the icon shows up as intended.

After this, toggling back and forth works properly with no delay or flashing.

I think this effect is due to the image needing to load or something. Is there a way to preload the image so it's primed and ready when needed?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for the replies. I was aware of the perf issues with `OpacityMask`, but chose to use it anyway because it's convenient. :) This is a fixed-size list and it wasn't hurting the scrolling performance. The issue didn't become apparent when I just displayed the icons, but when I added this toggle effect it became evident. The answer ended up being converting my images to XAML paths using Expression Design, then setting their `Fill` property to the theme foreground color. Works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend converting the image to a XAML Path and using a Fill of PhoneBackgroundBrush or PhoneForegroundBrush to handle the themes. You will get the benefit of a scalable vector image and it can be fully offloaded to the GPU

Comment: Thanks, Matt. This was the ticket. I used Expression Design to do the conversions--in one case I converted a .design file, and the other was a regular .png. Perf is excellent, and it simplified my XAML as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard to tell fully without a repro project, but here's a couple of suggestions.

1. You could always pre-load your images (by loading them into BitmapImage's etc) if this is indeed your issue (and then set the image source to these variables). Pay attention to memory usage in this scenario if your images are large!
2. OpacityMask is evil (on the phone). We constantly tell people this - since OpacityMask cannot be calculated on the GPU we do it all in software, which means you get bad performance (especially since it's all done on the UI thread). Best Practice: Do Not Use OpacityMask.
3. If this is Mango, make sure you have the correct [CreateOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.createoptions.aspx), using DelayCreation is awesome for general performance but can have a pop-in effect, which may be what you are seeing (since the image is loaded off-thread we will display UI before the image is loaded, and then redraw when the image is completely loaded + decoded).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you are using `OpacityMask` inside your `Button` styles, and you have a lot of `Buttons`.

`OpacityMask` cannot be computed by the GPU. It will be running on your UI thread and causing redrawing to happen.

You probably just want to create two different images for your dark and light theme instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the change is actual visible to the human eye, then you're probably not doing proper virtualization.

Try with 5-10 items, see if the issue persists? Also, we'd need to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue when i had nested grids too deeply, what silverlight will do is redraw things multiple times and then settle down if have too many user controls within user controls.